# How can I maximize the reproduction rate of animals?

Tags: banished

So I've managed to acquire my first animals, and I'm trying to figure out how to maximize their rate of reproduction.  My first thought was to split my animals into two different pastures, but I'm not sure if this will actually help or hurt the rate of reproduction. The help menu states that animals in a pasture not being worked will reproduce slower, and I'm assuming this applies to pastures with only one herdsmen as well. I'm also not sure if the number of animals in the pastures makes a difference (that is, will 4 sheep reproduce faster than 2 sheep?).

What affects the reproduction rate of animals, and how can I use this to maximize their reproduction rate?

Comment: By the way, animals seem to reproduce asexually in banished. Even a single animal will be enough to start a livestock industry. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157021/what-are-the-rules-for-animal-mating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a 20x20 pasture and allow it to fill to the max with animals. Set both workers to work on it. Basically the more animals the faster they breed.

Answer (score 0):

Disable production in animal pen . They will breed faster  without being slaughtered